# Customized Dropdown Field Component not compatible with Redux-Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have the following problem.
I have customized my own DropDown component using  elements.
I want this element to interact with Redux-Form as I want to save the value that is selected. 
This does not work:

```
<Field
name="name"
component={MyCustomizedDropDown}
data={myData}/>
```

The other option was to use the "input" props but as I am using  elements, this is not possible.
Can someone give me a solution? Thanks.

MyCustomizedDropDown component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class MyCustomizedDropdown extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...this.props,
      items: this.props.items || [],
      selectedItem: this.props.items[0] || this.props.selectedItem,
      showItems: false,
      isOpened: false
    };
    this.dropDown = this.dropDown.bind(this);
    this.selectedItem = this.selectedItem.bind(this);
  }

  dropDown() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showItems: !prevState.showItems
    }));
  }

  selectedItem(item) {
    this.setState({
      selectedItem: item,
      showItems: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { input } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="select-box--wrapper">
        <div className="select-box--toggle" onClick={this.dropDown}>
          <div className="select-box--selected-item">
            {this.state.selectedItem && this.state.selectedItem.value}
          </div>
          <MyImage
            className={`${
              this.state.showItems
                ? "select-box--arrow-rotated"
                : "select-box--arrow"
            }`}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="select-box--main">
          <div
            {...input} \\THIS DOES NOT WORK
            className="select-box--items">
            {this.state.data.map(item => (
              <div key={item.id} onClick={() => this.selectedItem(item)}>
                {item.value}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


MyCustomizedDropdown.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array,
  selectedItem: PropTypes.array,
  input: PropTypes.object
};

export default MyCustomizedDropdown;
```

Comment: The solution with the input props works only if the element is <select>.

Comment: Your customized component has to use the same props as any other component passed to `Field`. Is it customized right? Without seeing `MyCustomizedDropDown` it's impossible to tell what the problem is.

Comment: If you could post your `MyCustomizedDropDown` code, that would be helpful

Comment: @BenLorantfy you can see my component up.

Comment: @cfraser you can see my post now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

redux-form only works with "controlled" components. That means the component needs a prop that a parent uses to tell it what it's value is. For example, the following is a controlled component:

```
<TextField 
  value={this.state.inputValue} 
  onChange={(value) => this.setState({ inputValue: value })} 
/>
```

Note that we're telling the `TextField` component what it's value is. You need to change your component to work the same way. The only caveat here is that redux-form injects a prop called `input` that is an object containing `value` and `onChange` (and a few other things), instead of directly injecting `value` and `onChange`.

So for the example above, it needs to work like this to support `redux-form`:

```
<TextField 
  input={{
    value: this.state.inputValue,
    onChange: (value) => this.setState({ inputValue: value })
  }}
/>
```

Here's your component written as a "controlled" component, in a way that should work with redux-form:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class MyCustomizedDropdown extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showItems: false
    };
    this.dropDown = this.dropDown.bind(this);
    this.selectedItem = this.selectedItem.bind(this);
  }

  dropDown() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showItems: !prevState.showItems
    }));
  }

  hideDropdownItems() {
    this.setState({
      showItems: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { input } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="select-box--wrapper">
        <div className="select-box--toggle" onClick={this.dropDown}>
          <div className="select-box--selected-item">
            {this.input.value && this.input.value.value}
          </div>
          <MyImage
            className={`${
              this.state.showItems
                ? "select-box--arrow-rotated"
                : "select-box--arrow"
            }`}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="select-box--main">
          <div
            className="select-box--items">
            {this.state.data.map(item => (
              <div 
                key={item.id} 
                onClick={() => {
                  this.input.onChange(item)
                  this.hideDropdownItems();
                }}
              >
                {item.value}
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


MyCustomizedDropdown.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array,
  selectedItem: PropTypes.array,
  input: PropTypes.object
};

export default MyCustomizedDropdown;
```

- Note we tell `MyCustomizedDropdown` what it's value is using `this.props.input.value`
- We call `this.props.input.onChange` if the component wants to change it's value. Since it can't do it on it's own, it needs to tell it's parent it wants to change value.
- The parent needs to respond to `onChange` and update `MyCustomizedDropdown`'s value

For example, this is how you'd use your component without `redux-form`:

```
<MyCustomizedDropdown 
  input={{
    value: this.state.dropDownValue,
    onChange: (value) => this.setState({ dropDownValue: value })
  }}
/>
```

And with redux-form, you can simply do the following, since redux-form manages all that stuff for you:

```
<Field
  component={MyCustomizedDropdown}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be handling the value of the input in the input's state. `MyCustomizedDropDown` should receive the `handleChange` function, `items` and `selectedItem` as props. The only thing that should be in the component's state is it's open or not.